# On jupyter notebook, how to use code to release running memory after executing all the cells, without clicking the restart button manually

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Is there a code to clear the memory of a notebook? I'm using for loop to save the dataframe to a csv. But when the loop increase, the running memory is also increasing. When overflowing, the kernel of notebook can't work. Can anyone tell me the reason why the memory is increasing? My idea is to clear jupyter memory without shutting down the notebook, so it will avoid the problem to out of memory. I would like to hear other better suggestions.The code is as follows.

```
num = 2062
for date in tqdm(trade_day[num:num+70]):
    # data is a dataframe, when saving it to a csv file, the size of file is about 3 to 4 MB
    data = alpha(enddate=date, index=stock_list, fq='pre')
    data.to_csv(str(date)+'.csv')
```